# JS - Programmatically send element with onclick

Tags: javascript

```
<button id="button1">Button</button>    
document.getElementById("button1").onclick=function(){ ???.style.display="none" };
```

As you can see above, how could I change the style to hide it with the onclick?
(and no, I don't want to do `<button onclick="x">`)

Comment: You want to change the button upon it is being clicked?

Comment: Use `this` or `event.target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this

```js
document.getElementById("button1").onclick=function(e){ e.target.style.display="none" };
```

```html
<button id="button1">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `srcElement` or `target`. (`target` is standard and `srcElement` is alias.)

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener( "click", e => {
  e.srcElement.style.display = "none";
} );
```

```html
<button id="button1">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
   document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";
});
```

```html
<button id="button1">Button</button>
```

You can use `addEventListener` and change the style on click.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
   document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";
});
```

`<button id="button1">Button</button>`

Comment: how does this answer the question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` inside the click handler to refer to the element clicked:

```js
document.getElementById("button1").onclick=function(){
  this.style.display="none";
};
```

```html
<button id="button1">Button</button>
```

Using `this` means you could (if you wanted to) use the same handler function on multiple elements. You could also add the event handler with `addEventListener` as an alternative - `this` still refers to the element the handler is attached to.